# Understanding Linux scheduling when pthreads are involved

Tags: linux, pthreads, real-time, scheduler

through the discussion of another problem, see [Debugging strange error that depends on the selected scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099178), I ran into some questions about the scheduling of my threads. I am on Linux 2.6.x, running with root-rights and using pthreads to do parallel things in a timing critical application written in C/C++.

I'll try to give some short, boiled down, snippets to explain my question:

In main I somewhere at the beginning do:

```
struct sched_param sp;
memset(&sp, 0, sizeof(sched_param));
sp.sched_priority = 99;
sched_setscheduler(getpid(), SCHED_RR, &sp);
```

I understand this to be the code that switches my program to use the RR-Scheduler, running at max. priority.

When starting a pthread, I do:

```
sched_param param;
pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
pthread_attr_getschedparam(&attr, &param);
param.sched_priority = priority;
pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_RR);
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param);
```

I understand this, to be the code that switches the thread that's gonna be started to RR-Scheduler, using the priority given in 'priority'. 
Is that going to work equivalently if main would **not** switch the scheduler?

What I do not understand is, if it is necessary to call that code in main? (The main-function does not do anything than starting everything and then block on keyboard input.)
Where can I find precise documentation of how this works. I don't think the manpages do a good job on explaining the background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another Question is, what happens, if separate multithreaded processes run in parallel? How will the processor time be distributed between those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux by default, uses the [ntpl (Native POSIX Thread Library)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) implementation which considers a thread as a light-weigth process, so the scheduler schedules threads with other processes.

On FreeBSD, you have the "original" [pthread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) implementation that allows you to specify threads scheduling policy but threads are not scheduled as process on default (unless PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM parameter is set)

So, in your example, your thread is scheduled as a standard process with a high priority so it will be in competition with all others processes with the same level of priority, your main process also.

If your time-critical stuff is in your thread, avoid to give a high priority to your main process, it will make one less process in competition with your real time stuff.

I found a comparison between PThreads and NTPL [here](http://www.icir.org/gregor/tools/pthread-scheduling.html).

Comment: So it has no mentionable effect to switch the main-task to the RR-scheduler on a Linux-system, assuming the main-task does not do anything useful, and it is absolutely sufficient to switch only the threads? Not even with respect to running multiple multithreaded programs?

Comment: On a NTPL implementation, yes, your thread is considered as any other process in the system, no priority inheritance available ;)

Comment: `getconf GNU_LIBPTHREAD_VERSION` tells about the threading implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The NPTL implementation is 1:1 model; a thread in user space and a process in kernel space which is call LWP.
A LWP scheduled by kernel has the content scope of PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM.