# pthread_mutex_lock locks, but no owner is set

Tags: c, pthreads

I've been working on this one for a few days -

As a background, I'm working on taking a single-threaded C program and making it multi-threaded. I have recently discovered a new deadlock case, but when I look at the mutex in gdb I see that

__lock=2 yet __owner=0

This is not a recursive mutex. Has anyone seen this? The program I'm working on is a daemon and this case only happens after executing at a high-throughput rate for over 20 minutes (approximately) and then relaxing the load. If you have any ideas I'd be grateful.

Edit - I neglected to mention that all of my other threads are idle at this time.

Cheers

Comment: Some source, any source to establish context would be really helpful.

Comment: @nos I run it in valgrind a lot to check that things are normal, but I will do that some more to see if I've made some new mistakes.

Comment: @Josh - The code overall is over 200k lines. The daemon tracks timed tasks by placing the in a queue in order and checking periodically to see if they are ready to be executed, so the only time this object and its mutex are looked at are to inspect if it is ready to be executed. If it is, it is removed from the queue and the function is called. Other than that it is only accessed to check its timing when other objects are inserted in order.

Comment: If your mutex havn't been properly initialized, you could get results like this.

Comment: @nos - that was my first thought, but this mutex is always initialized (it is only created in one function).

Comment: @dbeer: Ok, so I think 2 means contended (0 unlocked, 1 locked). You say your other threads are idle. Has any other thread died while waiting for the mutex?

Comment: @dbeer I have the same issue using an errorcheck mutex, but it happens immediately on startup every time.  No users, no count, no owner, yet deadlock.  The lock is only locked in a single place and unlocked in a single place and there's no way to leave it locked.

`__lock=2,__count=0,__owner=0,__nusers=0,__kind=2,__spins=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is due to a limitation of the pthread library. Whenever I have found parts of the code that use excessive locking and unlocking and heavily stressed that section of the code, I have had this kind of failure. I have solved them by re-writing these sections to minimize their locking, which is easier code to maintain (less error checking when re-acquiring potentially freed objects) and eliminates some overhead.

Answer (score 5):

This is to be expected. A normal (non-recursive, non-errorchecking) mutex has no need to store its owner, and some time can be saved skipping the step of looking up the caller's thread id. (This makes little difference on x86 but can be a huge difference on platforms like MIPS with broken ABIs, where there is no thread register and getting the thread id incurs a fault into kernelspace.)

The deadlock you're seeing it almost certainly due either to the thread trying to lock a mutex it already holds, or an actual logic error where two or more threads are each waiting for mutexes the other holds.

Comment: I have to disagree - it isn't normal. The way I've tracked down deadlock in the past is by checking who owns the mutex and then inspecting that. An additional detail I should've mentioned is that all other threads are idle at this point (I will edit my post). Also, how does a non-recursive mutex have a lock of 2? My understanding is that only recusive mutexes can have a lock value > 1.

Comment: This is all very implementation-specific, but I doubt the `lock` field is the reference count. It's almost surely just the atomic-exchange-for-locking field. I suspect 0 means unlocked, 1 means locked and uncontended, and 2 means locked with potential waiters. If in doubt, read the source.

Comment: @dbeer: R.. is actually right, normal mutexes don't save the owner, IIRC it's saved on recursive and error-checking mutexes,

Comment: I'm going to try making it a recursive mutex and seeing what I get.

Comment: The glibc source code suggests all kinds of mutexes save the owner once a lock has been aquired in the \_\_pthread_mutex_lock function, nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c

Comment: Well, I'd say it could help with diagnostics/debugging, so not entierly useless.

Comment: @nos: yeah, I misremembered. `owner` is only _read_ on recursive and error-checking mutexes (and `robust` and `PI` mutexes).

Comment: By the way, a smarter implementation of mutexes would combine the `lock` and `owner` members into a single atomic int, and just use a dummy owner value (e.g. 1) without actually looking it up for normal-type mutexes.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed the issue I was having - stack corruption caused the `mutex.__data.__lock` value to get set to some ridiculous number (4 billion-ish) just prior to attempting the `pthread_mutex_lock` call.  See if you can set a breakpoint, or print debugging info on the value of `__lock` just prior to performing the lock operation, and I'm willing to bet it's invalid right before the deadlock occurs.