# How can I debug mutex issues on Mac OS X?

Tags: multithreading, macos, mutex

I am trying to get a gdb/lldb stub to work for a program I'm making, and right now it seems to deadlock the debugger, so I am (ironically) debugging lldb on my machine to try to figure out where things go wrong.

lldb is trying to lock a mutex and seems to deadlock on that.

On Windows, I know that you can use [WinDBG magic in kernel debugging mode](http://www.usenetmessages.com/view.php?c=microsoft&g=5322&id=347894&p=0) to figure out who acquired the mutex first, and on Linux I know that `pthread_mutex_t` isn't opaque and you can use it to [figure out which thread is holding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483094/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-thread-holding-a-mutex) very simply.

What about Mac OS X? What can I do if I want to know which thread owns a mutex?

For the record, I've tried searching opensource.apple.com for the actual definition of the mutex structure, without much luck, but it doesn't mean it's not there.