# How to get thread id of owning thread for a locked mutex in pthreads

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix, mutex

A thread has a mutex of type `pthread_mutex_t` locked for itself. Another thread wants to know the thread id of the thread holding this locked mutex.

There are two types of thread ids as I understand. The POSIX/pthread thread id, returned by `pthread_self()`, and the linux thread id returned by the system call `gettid()`. These two are independent and have no relation, AFAIK (please correct me If I am wrong).

There is a field in the structure `pthread_mutex_t`, `int __owner` which stores the thread id of the thread that current holds the lock. This field can be accessed by,

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int tid;
tid = mutex.__data.__owner;
```

As described here - [Is it possible to determine the thread holding a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483094/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-thread-holding-a-mutex).

This `__owner` field has the linux system thread id (as would be returned by `gettid()`) and not the POSIX/pthread thread id (as would be returned by `pthread_self()`) .

I want to compare whether the current scheduled thread is owning the mutex or not. So, I should be comparing `pthread_self()` with the `__owner` value.

I could use `gettid()` instead of `pthread_self()`, but I am restricted to use `pthread_self()` only. (some portability features).

Is there any way to correctly determine the thread id of the locked mutex which would return `pthread_t` and not the system thread id?

I will appreciate any help, Thanks!

Regards,

Yusuf Husainy.

Comment: Since you are poking around inside what is technically an opaque object (the pthread_mutex_t), it seems a bit late to be worrying about portability issues ?  I guess what you need to do is construct a map of `__owner` value to `pthread_self()`, which each pthread could add itself to when it starts.  (That map would need to be protected by a mutex, from which the `__owner` value could be extracted when the pthread "registers" itself.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to determine the thread holding a mutex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483094/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-thread-holding-a-mutex) Please how does your question differ from the one you linked?

Comment: @alk, I understand that, My question differs becuase I want to know a way to get the thread id of type pthread_t, and not the system TID type. The linked question does not give any resolution to this.

Comment: So you agree the two questions are the same. I doubt you get the answer for your question, as the answers to the other question were, that there isn't an answer. For the latter workarounds were proposed.

Comment: Just code exactly what you want. I'd suggest using a separate mutex to protect the owner variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

> These two are independent and have no relation, AFAIK (please correct me If I am wrong).

That is correct. from `man pthread_self`:

> The thread ID returned by pthread_self() is not the same thing as the
>   kernel thread ID returned by a call to gettid(2).

2)

> so, I should be comparing pthread_self() with the __owner value

That is incorrect, `man pthread_self`:

> Thread identifiers should be considered opaque: any attempt to use a
>   thread ID other than in pthreads calls  is  non-portable  and  can 
>   lead to unspecified results.

3)

> Is there any way to correctly determine the thread id of the locked mutex which would return pthread_t and not the system thread id?

I guess, no. pthread_mutex_t has the field `int __owner;` and does not have  any field like `pthread_owner` that would contain pthread_t of the thread:

```
/* Data structures for mutex handling.  The structure of the attribute
   type is not exposed on purpose.  */
typedef union
{
  struct __pthread_mutex_s
  {
    int __lock;
    unsigned int __count;
    int __owner;
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
    unsigned int __nusers;
#endif
    /* KIND must stay at this position in the structure to maintain
       binary compatibility.  */
    int __kind;
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
    int __spins;
    __pthread_list_t __list;
# define __PTHREAD_MUTEX_HAVE_PREV      1
#else
    unsigned int __nusers;
    __extension__ union
    {
      int __spins;
      __pthread_slist_t __list;
    };
#endif
  } __data;
  char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_MUTEX_T];
  long int __align;
} pthread_mutex_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the stack trace for this? For example, if I use the pstack command on my multi-threaded app with a locked mutex I see the following:

```
# pstack <PID>

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fb94a4f4700 (LWP 25157)):
#0  0x00000034a7e0e264 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000034a7e09508 in _L_lock_854 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00000034a7e093d7 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x000000000040af63 in read_from_pbx_loop(void*) ()
#4  0x00000034a7e079d1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00000034a7ae88fd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fb949cf3700 (LWP 25158)):
#0  0x00000034a7aaca3d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000034a7ae1be4 in usleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000004074f0 in read_from_agent_loop(void*) ()
#3  0x00000034a7e079d1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00000034a7ae88fd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fb94a4f6720 (LWP 25156)):
#0  0x00000034a7aaca3d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000034a7ae1be4 in usleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x000000000040c600 in main ()
```

So you can get a stack trace of your thread and use some simple heuristic checks to see if the last step of the stack trace for your thread is `__lll_lock_wait`.