# Mutex Owner and lock status in vxworks

Tags: c++, vxworks

I am new to VxWorks and working in a C++ project on **VxWorks** platform. I want to know whether there is a way to know the owner of a **pthread mutex**(thread Id) and also the status of the mutex(locked or unlocked). In Linux we can get these info by using **mutex.__data.__owner** for ownership details. But in VxWorks I am not able to see the __data member in pthread_mutex_t. Can somebody please help me in solving this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- [Is it possible to determine the thread holding a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483094/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-thread-holding-a-mutex)
- **pthread_mutex_lock**
  Status of lock/unlock can be determined by the return value.

Hope it answers the above question asked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not able to find the .__data.__owner field of a mutex variable in vxworks. Can you help me in solving this issue