# pthread_join hangs indefinitely __lll_lock_wait_private()

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

I have multithreaded application where I spawn a few threads and do a `pthread_join` upon completion.

The main thread spawns threads and waits on `pthread_join()` for the worker threads to join. I am facing a issue where the main thread is waiting indefinitely in `pthread_join()` and all the worker threads have exited, leading the program to hang.
I identified that all worker threads have exited by checking `info thread` on gdb since it lists only the main thread.
 Its is known that calling `pthread_join()` on a exited thread will return immediately. But this seems different. This is the gdb stack trace.

```
#0  0x00007f45fefebeec in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f45fef68a6f in _L_lock_5333 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f45fef62408 in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f45ffbe5088 in _dl_deallocate_tls () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x00007f45ff9bde67 in __free_stacks () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f45ff9bdf7f in __deallocate_stack () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007f45ff9bff93 in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007f45f87a6fe1 in waitForWorkerThreadsToExit () at src/server.c:133
#8  ServerLoop (arg=<optimized out>) at src/server.c:662
#9  0x00007f45ff9bee25 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x00007f45fefde34d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I am on `CentOS7 and Linux kernel 3.10`

Can someone help? TIA

Comment: `_dl_deallocate_tls` sounds like it has to do with thread-local storage; do any of your threads use that feature?  If so, you might try temporarily disabling it and see if that makes the fault go away.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes we use thread-local storage extensively. I am afraid that it cant be disabled.

Comment: You say, "the worker threads have exited." What does that mean? What caused them to "exit?" Your main thread appears to be waiting for a mutex. Is it possible that one of the "workers" was forcibly _killed_ while holding the lock?

Comment: To get help, you need to add a few things: 1. you should tell which exact version of GLIBC you are using. 2. you should install libc6-dbg or similar package (`debuginfo-install -y ...`) and get the "hang" stack trace with file/line info. With that, we'll be able to tell *which* lock `libc.so.6` is blocking on.

Comment: (GNU libc) 2.17 is the glibc version @EmployedRussian

Answer (score 0):

One of the other threads is leaving without relinquishing the lock. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483094/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-thread-holding-a-mutex) you can check the thread id for owner of this mutex to know which thread is the culprit.