# Possible to get thread owner of GMutex lock?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-safety, glib

I've noticed it's possible to get [the thread holding the mutex lock on a ptread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483094/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-thread-holding-a-mutex).

Is the same possible for a GMutex? I didn't find any references in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. The [entire `GMutex` API](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#g-mutex-init) is here, and does not contain methods for getting the owning thread.